# CakePHP HTML qoute encoding issues

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I’m working on cakephp 1.3. I’m finding issue in character encoding. I’ve two model **Keyword** and **Group**, such that Keyword belongs to Group. What I’m trying to do is to perform full text query in model Keyword.

```
function geParentKeyword($keyword) {    

//$keyword = *Acupuncturist*;   Assuming this as input
$match = html_entity_decode("MATCH(Keyword.keyword) AGAINST (\"".trim($keyword)."\" IN BOOLEAN MODE)" );
return $this->find('first', array('fields' =>array('Group.name'), 'conditions' =>array($match) ));          
}
```

I got wrong results with this query. I debug the query and I got this

```
SELECT `Group`.`name` 
FROM `keywords` AS `Keyword` 
LEFT JOIN `groups` AS `Group` ON (`Keyword`.`group_id` = `Group`.`id`)  
WHERE MATCH(`Keyword`.`keyword`) AGAINST (&quot;*Acupuncturist*&quot; IN BOOLEAN MODE)   
LIMIT 1"
```

The query is perfect  but here the issue is at $match cake converts double quotes into `&quot;` I tried with html_entity_decode and str_replace() but they show the same query.

For more details.

**Core.php**

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

**Database.php**

```
var $default = array(
        ….
        'encoding' => 'UTF8',
    );
```

Expected result

```
MATCH(Keyword.keyword) AGAINST (' *Acupuncturist* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Please guide me what is the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the `$keyword` look like after calling `getParentKeyword`? Print it out directly after the function head...

Comment: it show *Acupuncturist* which is valid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve this by myself.

It was due to debug mode, I disable debug mode. It works only

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Comment: Downvoted this as this won't have fixed it. It will have hidden the error condition. Debug mode has no bearing on character encoding...

Comment: It's hidden the symptom. The cause still remains. It will come back and bite you...

Comment: @RichardAtHome  agree this is not the solution, I'm using cakephp 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
$match = "MATCH(Keyword.keyword) AGAINST ('".trim($keyword)."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Comment: @MoyedAnsari I would repeat my question: What does the `$keyword` look like after calling `getParentKeyword`? Print it out directly after the function head...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$match = 'MATCH(Keyword.keyword) AGAINST (\''. html_entity_decode(trim($keyword)) .'\' IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
```