# Find all in CakePHP is dumping a semicolon in my view

Tags: cakephp, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I don't know what exactly is happening with my CakePHP app. It worked last week and I have literally changed nothing with that particular file.

When I use find 'all' in my controller it dumps a semi-colon in my view even if there is nothing in the view file.

Here is my code

```
$evts = $this->Event->find('all');
```

There is nothing in my view file. I don't know if it makes a difference but I'm using a json view.

As requested here is the complete code for the action

```
public function search(){ 
        $this->Event->recursive = 2;
        $conditions = array(); 

        if(!empty($this->request->query['name'])){
            $conditions = array('Event.name LIKE ' => "%"  . str_replace(" ","%", $this->request->query['name']) . "%");
        }

        if(!empty($this->request->query['home'])){
            $conditions = array('Event.home_team_id' => $this->request->query['home']);
        }

        if(!empty($this->request->query['away'])){
            $conditions = array('Event.away_team_id' => $this->request->query['away']);
        }

        $limit = 25;
        if(!empty($this->request->query['limit'])){
            $limit = $this->request->query['limit'];
        }

         //$evts =  $this->Event->find('all',array('conditions'=>array($conditions),'order' => array('Event.start_time'),'limit'=>$limit));
         $evts = $this->Event->find('all');
        $this->set('events',$evts);


    }
```

Everything in the view has been commented out ... but here is the code anyway

```
$results = array();
$i = 0; 

 foreach ($events as $event) {
     $results[$i]['id'] = $event['Event']['id'];
     $results[$i]['label'] = $event['Event']['name'] . "(" . date_format(date_create($event['Event']['start_time']), 'D, jS M Y') . ")";
     $results[$i]['value'] = $event['Event']['name'];
     $results[$i]['home_team_name'] = $event['HomeTeam']['name'];
     $results[$i]['away_team_name'] = $event['AwayTeam']['name'];
     $results[$i]['sport_name'] = $event['Sport']['name'];
     $results[$i]['tournament_name'] = $event['Tournament']['name'];
     $results[$i]['start_time'] = $event['Event']['start_time'];
     $results[$i]['img'] = $event['Event']['img_path'];
     $results[$i]['listener_count'] = 0; //TODO Get the follower count
     $i++;
 }
echo json_encode($results);
```

Display
[image: This is what it displays]

Comment: please add complete code of action which contains this code

Comment: @MoyedAnsari I have added the complete code

Comment: there is nothing in search.ctp ? please debug $evts in action.

Comment: I have also found that if I set recursive to 1 or remove it completely then this behaviour does not occur

Comment: turn off your debug mode and then check.
See this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/11134571/1239506

Comment: @MoyedAnsari I turned off debug mode and the issue still exists

Comment: please add code of view. Also please check the Layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46411/discussion-between-temigiwa-and-moyed-ansari)

Answer (score 0):

If you changed nothing with that particular file then perhaps you have installed callbacks (either in the controller or in the **model**) that echo that ";". Look for 'afterFind' calls...

Search your model and your controller folders for "echo statement". In fact you should search your entire app folder except for the Views folder.